# Text Comparison using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to compare the log files from two different file using python

Log Format:
Datetime Object MethodName Paramters

Parameters can be of different format like list or dictionary
For example,

Data from File 1:

```
Params1 [{ [
Id
Name [ [
Place
Animal
Thing]],
Done]
[Id
Name [ [
Place
Animal
Thing]],
Done]
[Id
Name [ [
Place
Animal
Thing]],
Done]
}],
```

Data from File 2:

```
Params1 [{ 
[Id
Name [ [
Place
Animal
Thing]],
Done]                
[Id
Name [ [
Place
Animal
Thing]],
Done]
}]
```

In file 1, the item is repeated 3 times whereas in file 2 item is repeated 2 times.Like this there may be lists and dictionaries.But while reading from the log file,each line is read as text. How to compare the data in two files? Is there a way to find out that one particular sequence of text has occurred 3 times in one file and 2 times in another file

Comment: Where is your python code? Read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I dont have code, as i dont know how to apply the logic here. I just have the file formats. No Code

Comment: Use `json.loads`, then compare objects instead.

Comment: Data is not in json format :(

Comment: Is it possible to change the output format of those files, to make them easier to parse?

Comment: Do you just need to know if the files containing the same data or there is more information you need to get out of it?

Comment: I want to know  if the data is same and also the number of times a group of elements in repeated. For example, [Id
Name [ [
Place
Animal
Thing]],
Done]         occurs twice